# How to Embed PDF in browser in Django instead of downloading it?

Tags: django

My problem is that the browser downloads the `pdf` instead of displaying it.

I tried some solutions from this site ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393001/display-a-pdf-in-object-embed-django?r=SearchResults&s=2|57.8286)) but none of them worked for me.

I use this code in my `html` file and nothing else:

```
{% load static %}
<body>
    <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" title="SamplePdf" width="500" height="720">
        <embed src="{% static 'test.pdf' %}" >
    </object>
</body>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying PDF has nothing in common with Django, you can handle it with pure HTML:

[Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Have you tried:

```
<embed src="{% static 'test.pdf' %}" width="500" height="375" 
 type="application/pdf">
```

?

Comment: i found what's the problem. its because i use IDM to download files and IDM has a default settings to download pdf files directly. when i changed them.it works fine